# should i use All-Caps to execute a MySQL Command for it to work?

Tags: php, mysql

some people type commands in MySQL like this:

"select * from `RegisterUser` where pid = '".$uploadPid."'"

and some type it like this

"SELECT * FROM `RegisterUser` WHERE pid = '".$uploadPid."'"

what's the best? should i scream or not

Comment: Please read this first.  In sum, it depends if your server in Windows or Linux:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL isn't case sensitive, no need to scream. It's good practice to capitalize the commands anyways, just for readability. Table names can be case sensitive.